# NoClassDefFoundError on org/apache/cxf/jaxb/JAXBToStringStyle

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, cxf, jax-ws

Good day,

I am using apache cxf and spring boot to build a web service but when I try to call the endpoint, it gives me this error:

```
    WARN 15936 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain      : Application {
endpointMethod has thrown exception, unwinding now

        org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org/apache/cxf/jaxb/JAXBToStringStyle
                [...]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxb/JAXBToStringStyle
```

Here is my configuration for the webservice:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

@Bean
public org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
    return new org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/cxf-api/*");
}

@Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
public SpringBus springBus() {
    return new SpringBus();
}


@Bean
public Conc2MGPService conc2MGPService() {
    return new RegistrationServiceEndpoint();
}

@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), concessionario2MGPService());
    endpoint.publish("/registration_endpoint");
    return endpoint;
}
```

and here my POM:

```
<project ...">
    <groupId>com.me.justin</groupId>
        <artifactId>registration-gateway-app</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>registration-gateway-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.justin</groupId>
            <artifactId>justin-soap-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What am I missing? 
What I am doing here is a simple log on the object passed on the request.

```
@Override
    public RegisterContract(RegisterContractRequest registerContractRequest) {
        log.info("RegisterContract" + registerContractRequest);
        return null;
    }
```

I think that something is missing in my POM but I can't figure out what.

Comment: You're scoping the dependency as runtime, e.g. it would be provided by the container at runtime. If you are using the embedded container, or is it not part of the container you deployed to you would need to compile that dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this dependency to your pom.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.18</version>
</dependency>
```

As a side note this jar is deprecated, try to update your dependencies. New version of the above jar is like below. ( But in order to use it, you have update your related dependencies)

```
<groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1</version>
```